# How to trim a string after a specific character in php

Tags: php, trim

I am new in PHP and I have some text saved in a variable. I am trying retrieve a the text followed of the first '/' character. Here is what i tried.

```
$var="xxxxx/ttt/tttt/tttt.txt";
echo $str . "<br />";
echo trim($str,"/");
```

The output must be `ttt/tttt/tttt.txt`.
I will highly appreciate if i can get some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with explode function

```
$var="xxxxx/ttt/tttt/tttt.txt";

$split = explode('/', $var,2); // it will expload by first occurance of / (delimeter)

//$split[0] will contain "xxxxx"

echo  $split[1]; // output = ttt/tttt/tttt.txt
```

Comment: $split[0] will contain "xxxxx" not $split[1]

Comment: @RuchishParikh yeah I have edit that

Comment: how to explode after the second '/'?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the duplication, here's your answer:

```
$data = "xxxxx/ttt/tttt/tttt.txt";

$whatIWant = substr($data, strpos($data, "/") + 1);

echo $whatIWant;
```